# Hide n:th text using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this list

```
<li id="field_7_div" class="field_block">
<div class="col_label">
<label class="form_field">How satisfied are you with <span class="aggregator_name">your aggregator</span>?</label>
<label class="form_required">*</label>
</div>
<div class="col_field">
<div class="radio" id="uniform-field_7_0"><span>
<input type="radio" class="form_radio" value="Very Satisfied" id="field_7_0" name="field_7" style="opacity: 0;">
</span></div>
<label for="field_7_0" class="form_choice_text">Very Satisfied</label>
<br>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-field_7_1"><span>
<input type="radio" class="form_radio" value="Satisfied" id="field_7_1" name="field_7" style="opacity: 0;">
</span></div>
<label for="field_7_1" class="form_choice_text">Satisfied</label>
<br>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-field_7_2"><span>
<input type="radio" class="form_radio" value="Neutral" id="field_7_2" name="field_7" style="opacity: 0;">
</span></div>
<label for="field_7_2" class="form_choice_text">Neutral</label>
<br>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-field_7_3"><span>
<input type="radio" class="form_radio" value="Unsatisfied" id="field_7_3" name="field_7" style="opacity: 0;">
</span></div>
<label for="field_7_3" class="form_choice_text">Unsatisfied</label>
<br>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-field_7_4"><span class="checked">
<input type="radio" class="form_radio" value="Very Unsatisfied" id="field_7_4" name="field_7" style="opacity: 0;">
</span></div>
<label for="field_7_4" class="form_choice_text">Very Unsatisfied</label>
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="field_7_length">
<div class="instruction" id="field_7_tip"></div>
</div>
</li>
```

I want to hide the text "Satisfied, Neutral, Unsatisfied" and just leave "Very Satisfied and Very Unsatisfied". Can you guys please tell me how to hide this text using Jquery? or CSS if it works in ***IE8***.

Comment: This is not Java related but Javascript

Comment: You could always use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-child).

Answer (score 3):

Only CSS

using [**adjacent sibling selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) :

```
#uniform-field_7_1 + label,
#uniform-field_7_2 + label,
#uniform-field_7_3 + label{display:none}
```

or [**attribute-selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

```
label[for="field_7_1"],
label[for="field_7_2"],
label[for="field_7_3"]{display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

if ids never change you can just hide with CSS

```
#uniform-field_7_1, #uniform-field_7_2,
#uniform-field_7_3 { display: none !important; }
```

and for labels use a jquery

```
$('label[for*="field_7_1"], label[for*="field_7_2"], label[for*="field_7_3"]').hide();
```

Comment: Then it'll hide the radio button too

Comment: If you need only hide the text just run the jQuery of answer